# convert tab delimited output to list of strings

Tags: r, shiny

I have an output that I receive from a Shiny app i'm building. The output looks like this:

```
[1] "wrong item"       "Wrong order"      "completely wrong"
```

it appears to be tab delimited but i'm not event sure of the format. I would need to be able to convert it to a pipe delimited list such as

```
df %>% 
    filter(str_detect(string, wrong item|Wrong order|completely wrong"))
```

is it possible at all? As a starting point I've tried to convert the output to a list but it's not letting me as there's no comma:

```
l<-paste("wrong item"       "Wrong order"      "completely wrong")
```

Thank you if you can help me it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need something like this?:

```
#If your output is x
x <- c("wrong item", "Wrong order", "completely wrong")

paste(x, collapse = "|")
# will give:
# [1] "wrong item|Wrong order|completely wrong"


# so in your example it could be: 

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(string, paste(x, collapse = "|")))

# OR 

df %>% 
  filter(str_detect(string, paste(c( "wrong item", "Wrong order", "completely wrong"), collapse = "|")))
```

Comment: thanks but my output is like this: "wrong item"       "Wrong order"      "completely wrong" ie not comma delimited.. it is kind of a wierd tab delimited format

Comment: @tezzaaa it's not tab delimited, that's just how a vector of characters is being printed. If you copy and run the first code above assigning x, then print x, you'll see it shows like your original post with the spaces in between.

Comment: Ah Sorry! i got confused. A big thank you for your help. I will try that